# Installing latex font as a system font for Adobe Flash

Tags: fonts, adobe

I've installed the fonts from the package:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and it works great in latex, but I imported the output file into adobe flash professional, and it needs to font map all the fonts, and everything looks messed up. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Your question might be off-topic

Comment: Use `xelatex` or `lualatex` wth a system font which can also be used by other applications.

Comment: The [STIX fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/) can be installed in your operating system and look like Times New Roman, like `mathptmx`. Also, the OpenType-enabled [XITS fonts](https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits-math) are available.

Comment: hey chris i installed stix and i'm getting similar errors. Any pointers? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179303/stix-font-not-in-adobe-illustrator