# Stix font not in Adobe Illustrator (Windows)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, windows, illustrator, stix

I compiled my latex document using `pdflatex` in `texstudio`. I have already installed the Windows *Stix* fonts in to the system fonts folder. However when I open the pdf output in Illustrator I get:
[image: 1]

and then the final output in illustrator looks like:
[image: 1]

when it should look like this:

[image: 1]

Comment: The font names refer to the Type1 fonts that are found in `<TEX root>/fonts/type1/public/stix`, not to the OpenType fonts.

Comment: yep i had a look, converted them to open types, installed them and still have the same issue

Comment: If you use Opentype fonts, compile with `Xe/LuaLaTeX`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that Illustrator cannot handle the builtin encoding of the math fonts. You could try to switch to `xelatex` or `lualatex`. Replace

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
```

with

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```

Then it uses the OpenType fonts.

Comment: i replaced what you said, and it solved the font issues, but now there are size issues where illustrator doesn't know how to size the symbols. ![image](http://i.imgur.com/gM0haEV.png)